# Freebsd gcc installed but not available

Tags: gcc, freebsd

I am new to Freebsd. I have installed gcc but unable to run it.

> root@mybook:/home/accessp # pkg install gcc
>   Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
>       ...
>       ...
>       ...
>   New packages to be INSTALLED:
>       gcc: 4.8.3_2
>
> The process will require 345 MB more space.
>      67 MB to be downloaded.
>
> Proceed with this action? [y/N]: y
>
> Fetching gcc-4.8.3_2.txz: 100%   67 MB  84.5k/s    13:52
>      Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
>
> [1/1] Installing gcc-4.8.3_2: 100%
>
> root@mybook:/home/accessp # gcc
>
> gcc: Command not found.

Where has gcc been installed? Or do I have to do some additional steps to complete installation?

### EDIT

I have seen in /usr/local/bin. Its not there. I have done a find for gcc and here is the result:

> /usr/libdata/gcc
>
> /usr/local/lib/gcc48/gcc
>
> /usr/local/libdata/ldconfig/gcc
>
> /usr/local/libexec/gcc48/gcc
>
> /usr/include/gcc
>
> /usr/ports/lang/gcc49/work/gcc-4.9-20141015/gcc
>
> /usr/ports/lang/gcc49/work/build/gcc
>
> /usr/ports/lang/gcc

Comment: It is in /usr/local/bin so make sure that is in your path.

Comment: Why downvote without giving reason? See the firsts line (Its a newbie question) and its not a path issue.

Comment: You're probably getting downvotes because this site is not for "Please teach me how to use FreeBSD" and "Please teach me how to install something on FreeBSD" questions. If you want a tutorial for using some form of *nix, you've come to the wrong site. Your question has nothing to do with using a compiler or programming - it's a "how do I do this thing using this OS" question.

Comment: other thing is do you need gcc specifically? `/usr/bin/cc` on freebsd is already clang. You only really need older gcc versions if the code you are working on requires something specific to that version

Comment: Run `pkg query '%Fp' gcc | grep /usr/local/bin` to see the executables the package installs.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can install multiple versions of `gcc` from ports, none of them actually installs itself simply as `gcc`, because that would cause conflicts.

The executable names have a suffix appended to them based on their version. In your case, look for `gcc48`.

Additionally, and depending on the shell you use you might have to use the `rehash` command after installing a new program to make the shell aware of it.